# regex: ignore potential matches after a "#"

Tags: regex

EDIT: Although I've marked this question with the `java` tag, I don't want a solution that requires java code. I just would like the pattern to be compatible with Java's regex implementation if possible (which unfortunately is not quite PCRE compatible). What I would like is just a single regex that produces the matches I want.

Suppose I have this string:

```
foo bar foo bar # foo bar foo bar
```

I'd like to match instances of "foo", but only if they are not after any "#" symbol (if one is present). In other words, I want this result:

```
foo bar foo bar # foo bar foo bar
^^^     ^^^
```

I tried using a negative look-behind like this:

```
(?<!#.*)\bfoo\b
```

...but this doesn't work because a look-behind cannot be of variable length. Any suggestions?

Comment: Split on `#` then deal with the first part.

Comment: Which language/tool are you using? A correct solution might vary depending on the used regex flavour.

Comment: What's the context/language/tool ? It's usually simpler to do it in two steps (like splitting then searching

Comment: @Toto: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now but this is just a simplified example; in practice splitting gets pretty messy. also, I'd like something that works in a text editor's "search and replace" function.

Comment: You could do [`foo(?=.*#)`](https://regex101.com/r/hw3VnI/1) if you know that the string has a `#` in it.

Comment: @nickb: Unfortunately I won't know if the string has a `#`.

Comment: Do you really need lookbehind at all? If you replace `^([^#]*)foo` with `\1bar`, you just replaced `foo` with `bar` as long as there's no `#` preceding; doesn't that meet the need?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `^([^#]*)foo` produces only a single match `foo bar foo` and not two `foo` matches.

Comment: @AlvinThompson, sure, but it'll match repeatedly if run repeatedly. I'm going for pragmatism and compatibility here (the latter meaning no dependencies on anything not present in POSIX ERE). I'd be quite surprised if you get an answer here that doesn't require extensions.

Comment: Java regex engine can handle constrained-width lookbehinds, so, you may try `(?<!#.{0,500})\bfoo\b` - this should work with strings of up to 500 chars. If your strings are of arbitrary length, this won't work for you though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That's good to know, but I was hoping for an answer that would work also in a text editor's "replace" function. I want everything with no compromises, so maybe I picked the wrong profession.  :)

Comment: What is the text editor? EmEditor? Atom? Notepad++? Notepad2? Vim? Maruo?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: In my case Brackets and NetBeans, but other developers here use other editors. I was hoping for a solution that was compatible with most regex flavors but that may not be in the cards.

Comment: No way, I doubt you can do that with a single pure regex solution then.

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the work

- (?=.*#) lookahead and gets all text before "#"
- global flag "g" repeats pattern

`/(?=.*#)(\bfoo\b)/g`

Comment: This doesn't work if the `#` is not present. I don't know if it will be or not.

Comment: This will also find an invalid second `foo` in `foo bar # foo bar # foo bar` since the middle `foo` is indeed followed by a `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `replaceFirst` method to remove text after `#` and then do a simple word match:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bfoo\\b");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input.replaceFirst("#.*$", ""));

while (matcher.find()) {
   System.err.printf("Found Match: %s%n", matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: I kind of like where you were going with your first answer. :)  As I mentioned in the comments on the question, this is actually a simplified case and splitting can get ugly. Also, I'd like something that works from a text editor's "search and replace" if I can get it.

Comment: I answered it after reading your comment but had to delete since you later tagged question as `java` as that feature only works with PCRE flavors.

Comment: Can the java matcher be set to be PCRE compatible?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Java regex is not powerful enough for doing it with a single regex.

- Lookbehind is fixed width, so that's not a solution.
- Lookeahead is only applicable when you can be sure that there is a `#` in the string.
- Java does not allow failing a match and then continuing searching at the end (like with SKIP/FAIL in PCRE). It always continues at the character after the last matching start.

`#.*|(\bfoo\b)` and then checking if the first matching group is defined would be a workaround here, but there's no pure way to just match `\bfoo\b` sequences.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but it's hard to conclusively prove it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with a single regex as others said already. But there is a workaround for this.

1. Select `#` and every thing after:

```
#.*
```

2. Copy highlighted part and paste it in parenthesis in place of
   `HERE`:

```
foo(?=.*\QHERE\E)
```

[image]

Comment: What tool are you using? Is this an IDE?